# Are Jehovah’s Witness men required to be clean shaven if they have been appointed to leadership roles?

Tags: jehovahs-witnesses

Is their any objection in 2023 to the wearing of a beard by JW men who have been appointed to leadership positions?

Comment: Is there any substance to the rumour I've heard that birthdays and blood transfusions are now a matter of conscience?  I can see how acknowledging a child is now a year older does not necessitate any action from the Elders, but having a blood transfusion?

Comment: @Lesley acknowledging that someone is officially  year older is not an issue. Nothing had changed on birthday celebrating.  Nothing new on blood transfusing.   There us a new update that you can watch on Jw.org this month that adjust some dress codes and softens stance in dealing with disfellowshipping

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Background:** Up until recently, Jehovah’s Witness men were not allowed to grow a beard.  This is based on Leviticus 19:27.

**In 1968, the May 12 issue of the Watchtower** magazine suggested that a beard would detract from their message because “the majority” of people classify individuals with beards as extremists or rebels against society.  In answer to [When Jesus Christ was a man on earth, did he wear a beard?](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/d/r1/lp-e/1968330),the article conceded that Jesus probably did have a beard:

> One of the commandments of the Law was: “You must not cut your side locks short around, and you must not destroy the extremity of your beard.” (Lev. 19:27) God doubtless gave Israel this law because among some pagans it was the practice to cut the beard in a certain fashion in worship of their gods. (Jer. 9:26; 25:23) Nevertheless, that law did not mean that a beard was not to be well kept, for in the Near East a well-groomed beard was considered a symbol of dignity and respectability.—2 Sam. 19:24.

> In recent years in many lands a beard or long hair on a man attracts immediate notice and may, in the minds of the majority, classify such a person undesirably with extremists or as rebels against society.

> Nevertheless, as already shown, it is apparent that Jesus did wear a beard, and so artistic representations of him in future Watch Tower publications will harmonize with the Scriptural evidence to that effect.

**However, on 15 December 2023 an official Jehovah’s Witness** [video](https://www.jw.org/en/news/region/global/2023-Governing-Body-Update-8/) was released by Governing Body member Stephen Lett saying it is now acceptable for men in the congregation who are in appointed positions to wear a beard providing it is neat and tidy.

> After prayerful consideration, the Governing Body has concluded that there is a need to clarify this matter. The Governing Body does not have an issue with brothers wearing beards. Why not? Because the Scriptures do not condemn the wearing of beards.

> Thus, whether a brother wears a beard is a personal decision. A Brother’s qualifications to serve as an elder, or ministerial servant, is based on his spirituality, not on whether he chooses to wear a beard. This direction also applies to special full-time servants at Bethel, and those in the field including special pioneers, missionaries, and circuit overseers. – Stephen Lett in [2023 Governing Body Update #8](https://www.jw.org/en/news/region/global/2023-Governing-Body-Update-8/)

**Answer:** There is now no objection for Jehovah’s Witness men who are in positions of ministerial leadership or those working at Bethel or in field service to have a (neat and tidy) beard.

Comment: @agarza - Thanks for editing the links.  I'm not quite there yet!  In deference to your observation about highlights in italics, I'm just sticking to bold print for headings.

Comment: You're welcome and thank you. For additional information, see [How do I write an accessible Stack Exchange post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/394687/how-do-i-write-an-accessible-stack-exchange-post).

Comment: @agarza - Understood the bit about using bold and italics, which was really helpful, but the rest of it went completely over my head (not being an I.T. expert).  Worth keeping the link for future reference, though.